# How can I work out the errors in my automation code?

Tags: java, selenium, appium, helper, appium-android

I've been watching a lot of youtube videos and following tutorials that have to do with Appium, Selenium and Android app automation. But I'm still not sure as to what's wrong in my code, I'm completely new to programming so I don't know how to decipher all of this.

This is my code:

```
package testcase;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class OpenOfferUp {


@Test
public void OpensOfferUp() throws MalformedURLException
{
    File OfferUp = new File("C:/Users/boung/Desktop/offerupapk");
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Virtual Device");
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "android");
    cap.setCapability("app", OfferUp);
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.offerup");
    cap.setCapability("activityName", "com.offerup.android.activities.SearchActivity");

    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

}


}
```

**This is what shows up in console**

```
`FAILED: OpensOfferUp
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: C. Last 110 characters read: {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "activityName": "com.offerup.android.activities.SearchActivity",
    "app": C
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-HCHDEFK', ip: '10.0.0.83', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.MapCoercer.lambda$null$0(MapCoercer.java:68)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.MapCoercer.lambda$apply$1(MapCoercer.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.read(JsonInput.java:280)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.getOss(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:336)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.<init>(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:172)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.NewAppiumSessionPayload.create(NewAppiumSessionPayload.java:134)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:175)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:94)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:95)
    at testcase.OpenOfferUp.OpensOfferUp(OpenOfferUp.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
`
```

Comment: Please post code and not an image.

Comment: just removed the image

Comment: Your json has `"app": C` (that's from the exception message). That's not valid json; you need quotes around the OfferUp string. You should jsonify the string using jackson (In forget the exact calls), which will handle escaping and such for you. But you also need to spend time to learn how to debug! Read exception messages, think about what they're telling you, ask yourself what might be going wrong. This is an absolutely vital programming skill!

Comment: Could you break this down so I could understand a little better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in capability `app`. You should provide an absolute local path or a remote http URL to your .apk file. But you insert a File object.

```
cap.setCapability("app", "C:/Users/boung/Desktop/offerupapk");
```

Note, that if your webdriver hub server on the remote machine, you have to copy your .apk there first

Comment: Thank you, the prior issue is now fixed but, now this appears in console and appium **remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: New app path 'C:/Users/boung/Desktop/offerupapk' did not have extension(s) '.apk'**

Comment: @DamoneWilliams try to add extension `.apk` :)